# Trying to run a couple of VMs using Vagrant. On running vagrant up command I get Call to virDomainCreateWithFlags failed: internal error

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

Trying to run a CentOS 7 VM on Virtual Box using vagrant on my Fedora 35 machine.
On running the run the `vagrant up` & `vagrant up --debug` commands I get the following message as output.

```
There was an error talking to Libvirt. The error message is shown
below:

Call to virDomainCreateWithFlags failed: internal error: /usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper --use-vnet --br=virbr0 --fd=27: failed to communicate with bridge helper: Transport endpoint is not connected
stderr=failed to get mtu of bridge `virbr0': No such device
```

Comment: From the vagrant tag: VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was making a rookie mistake of not properly defining the VM provider in `vagrant up` command. Running `vagrant up --provider virtualbox` fixed this issue.